# Oracle - open a sys_refcursor for an explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, cursor

I have a function that returns a `sys_refcursor` so that a Java application can process the results:

```
  function fn_stuff (in_array in t_id_array) return sys_refcursor is
    rc sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open rc for
        --query has been significantly shortened since most details are not 
        --relevant for this question.
        select * from some_table where id in table(in_array);
    return rc;
  end;
```

I'd also like to be able to use this function with PL/SQL. It would be very convenient to be able to reference the rowtype of this result like this:

```
  procedure sp_f is
    rc sys_refcursor;
    arr t_id_array ;
    r c_stuff%rowtype;
  begin
    arr := t_id_array('11','22','33','44');

    rc := pkg_stuff.fn_stuff(arr);
    loop
     fetch rc into r
     exit when rc%notfound;
     dbms_output.put_line(r.col1||' '||r.col2);
   end loop;
  end;
```

To do this, I'd need to declare the `SELECT` statement in `fn_stuff` as a proper cursor:

```
cursor c_stuff (in_array in t_id_array) is 
  select * from some_table where id in table(in_array);
```

So then I thought to update the function to simply reference the new cursor I declared:

```
  function fn_stuff (in_array in t_id_array) return sys_refcursor is
    rc sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open rc for
        select * from c_stuff(in_array);
    return rc;
  end;
```

Which yields:

```
Error(52,37): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

I could keep the `SELECT` statement as it was inside `fn_stuff` but it's still in development so it would be easier to just have the query in a single place.

Is there any way to open and return a sys_refcursor on a declared cursor?

I guess another option is that I could declare a record type which has all of the columns that are selected by the query, but since the query is still under development and columns may be added ore removed from the select, the record type would have to be kept in sync. But since the `sp_f` procedure only is interested in a handful of columns that probably won't change, I thought the `%rowtype` would be better.

Comment: Why not just `open rc for select * from some_table where id in table(in_array);`